# How to collapse methods in the NetBeans files by default?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

How can collapse methods in files by default? for example Java files.
When opening the file I found methods expanded.
So I want to make them collapsed by default.
Is there a feature in NetBeans to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse it by using the keymap:

i.e.

The default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

But you can adjust this in `Tools`->`Options`->`Keymap`.

they stay like that if you reopen the file.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+-. do collapse methods when the editor is opening.
But when reopen it again return to be expanded again.

Comment: then use intelli j it is there staying collapsed

Comment: thanx UlrichGiorgioJaeger will try it.